# Flutter how to post json array

Tags: dart, flutter

How to post below json array?

```
"LstUserOptions": [
  {
    "OptionID": "ca339e40-10cc-4459-b9ec-07f7df0f4c69"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add additional information to add some context to your question, including an attempt to solve the problem, which help us to better understand what you want.

Comment: *How to post below json array?* means what

Comment: I want to post that json array data in flutter body

    http.Response response = await http.post(
        Uri.encodeFull(ConfigApi.SAVE),
        body: body,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i found the solution :

```
List<Map> carOptionJson = new List();
CarJson carJson = new CarJson("ca339e40-10cc-4459-b9ec-07f7df0f4c69");
carOptionJson.add(carJson.TojsonData());

var body = json.encode({
  "LstUserOptions": carOptionJson
});

http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.encodeFull(ConfigApi.SAVE),
    body: body,
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});

class CarJson {
  String OptionID;
  CarJson(this.OptionID);
  Map<String, dynamic> TojsonData() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["OptionID"] = OptionID;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: u r awesome bro. i was searching for this thing 'Content-type': 'application/json'

Comment: it worked in my case too.

Answer (score 0):

how to done this work with dio package i send whole my data with dio and now i want send a array of json with it , is correct this code if assume my json array is body

```
FormData formData = new FormData.from({
"cars": body
});
response = await dio.post("url", data: 
formData);
```