# Post array using http in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart

Anyone know how to post array using `http`?

```
var headers = {"Accept": "application/json"};
      var url = "https://...."
      var response = await http.post(url,
          body: {
           ....
          },
```

I have a param named `commentList`. I need to pass `comment[0]`, `comment[1]`... inside body.

How to use `for loop` inside the body???

```
for(var i in list){
"comments"+"["+index+"]" = i;
   index ++; 
}
```

Here the postman key and value

[image]

Comment: What about JSONing that array?

Comment: @raina77ow any example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002196/flutter-how-to-post-json-array

Comment: @raina77ow I would like to post it as `comment[0]`,`comment[1]`.  Is the link provided work in my case?

Comment: just pass the whole array in jsonEncode @Tony

Comment: @raina77ow post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

```
int count = 0;

var url = "https://xxx";
      var response = await http.post(url,
          body: {
            for (var i in list) 'comments[${count++}]':i,
            ....
          },
          headers: headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to combine comments for specific reason you can do like this.

```
List commentList = ['comment1','comment2','comment3'];
Map<String, dynamic> body;
```

combine them:

```
String comments ='';
  
  commentList.forEach((comment){
    
    comments +=comment+' ';
    
  });
 body = {'combinedComments':comments};
```

then post :

```
var headers = {"Accept": "application/json"};
      var url = "https://...."
      var response = await http.post(url,
          body: this.body);
```

or just use json encode to convert your list to string;

```
Map<String,dynamic> body = {'comments' :jsonEncode(commentList)};
```

and use this as body to post.